# How do I index the argument of an excel worksheet function within a for loop in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a piece of code that indexes through a range of cells, writing the output of an excel worksheet function (in this case the Forecast() function) to each cell. However, I'm trying to index the inputs to the function as well, as these need to change.

Here's what I'm working with so far:

```
For i = Start To ForecastSize
        Worksheets("Data Inputs").Cells(i, 5).Formula = "=Forecast(Worksheets("Data Inputs").Cells(i,1),$D$2:D12,$A$2:A12)"
    Next i
```

In this case Start and ForecastSize are both variables particular to my data, but they're irrelevant to this, the index could be anything.

The first argument to the Forecast() function is what's giving me the issue. If I change that to a constant, say A12, then my code runs, but it writes the same forecast output to all of the i cells in the 5th column.

I'm getting a compile error: expected: end of statement

I read somewhere that strings within a function need double quotes, so I tried ""Data Inputs"" for the first argument of the Forecast() function, but then I get a Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `"=Forecast(" & Worksheets("Data Inputs").Cells(i,1) & ",$D$2:D12,$A$2:A12)"`

Comment: Thanks Scott! I also need to update the second and third arguments of the Forecast() function by indexing the known x's and y's. So right now it shows D2:D12 and A2:A12, but I want to be able to update the range each time through the loop to D2:D13 and A2:A13 and so on and so forth. Would I use a similar approach?

Answer (score 0):

This forecast is line forecast, maybe you can calculate a,b and make the formula more flexible.

y=a+bx

[image]